# How to copy a folder to another path using S3 with aws-sdk-php?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I'm using aws-sdk-php and I must copy a folder with all file to a new path

This is my solution:

```
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => $bucket, 'Prefix' => $folderToCopy));
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    $newPath = str_replace($folderToCopy, $whereToPaste, $object['Key']);

    $s3->copyObject(array(
        'Bucket'     => $bucket,
        'Key'        => $newPath,
        'CopySource' => "{$bucket}/{$object['Key']}"
    ));
}
```

Works fine, but with thousands of file require a lot of time..

Is there another solution?